# DateTime DayOfWeek not correct for dates of years in distant future

Tags: c#, date, datetime, dayofweek

I was experimenting with Dates in C#. I wrote a Console Application, whose main method is as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine()).DayOfWeek);
    }
}
```

Now this works for dates in *near* (I don't think I'm calling them near/distant correctly) future and past like dates in 2016, 2017, 1996, etc. But not for dates in 2999, 3000, etc.

What is the reason for this? I don't think it's because of leap years because 2019 works fine as well.

And not for Y*N*K either I think because I write the full year:

```
15/01/3000
```

**Working Inputs**:

```
31/12/2015
05/05/2019
```

**Inputs not producing correct results**:

```
15/01/2099
17/07/3000
```

Parsing is fine. It's not producing correct output. Like when it should return Friday, it returns Saturday, etc.

Comment: How do you enter those years exactly? Can you please show working inputs but not working inputs as well?

Comment: @SonerGönül See the edit please.

Comment: this is not valid datye

Comment: `15/01/3000` isn't parsable (for my current culture), the same way `15/01/2000` isn't.  However, `01/15/3000` works fine.  If you use `en-GB` culture, then `15/01/3000` works.

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture` by the way?

Comment: View the value of `DateTime.Parse("15/01/3000")` in the debugger, and tell us what is the value of `Year`, `Month` and `Day` properties.

Comment: Day 15, Month 1 and Year 3000. @YacoubMassad

Comment: And what does the `DayOfWeek` give you?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Wednesday

Comment: And why do you think that is a wrong value?

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ That is true output. And by the way, get a room guys.

Comment: @YacoubMassad No this is correct. Wait everything's messed up. I'll edit the question in a few mins with tests.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99338/question-34536312

Comment: Got it. It was a problem with Culture Settings. Month and Days were interchanged, and thus the error.

Answer (score 0):

UTC Dates will be wrong after 1-19-2038.  [UTC Date Glitch 2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)

Comment: Can you go back before 01-01-1901?

Comment: Yes. Tried 1 Feb 1856. Output OK.

Comment: Those inputs does not produce `Utc` as  `Kind`. Sorry but this is quite irrelevant.

Comment: Then it must be the culture settings as discussed above.

Comment: Downvoting. The `DateTime` of .NET has no overflow at 2038. You are confusing it with an entirely unrelated date representation. In .NET we use a 64-bit integer to count number of 1/10,000,000 parts of a second since 1 January 0001, and there is no overflow in 2038. The representation you think of (which is irrelevant in the scenario the asker describes) counts whole seconds since 1 January 1970 with a sign 32-bit integer.